# get user data from NbAuthOAuth2Token angular

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular, ngx-admin

i'm using NbAuthOAuth2Token like this

```
this.authService.onTokenChange()
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
  .subscribe((token: NbAuthOAuth2Token) => {
    this.token = null;
    if (token && token.isValid()) {
      this.token = token;
    }
  });
```

and in my login function like this

```
  login() {
    this.authService.authenticate('google')
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe((authResult: NbAuthResult) => {
      });
  }
```

how to get the user data? i'm using `scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',`